# Somando e ordenando linha de matrizes em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

O programa abaixo gera uma matriz aleatória, conforme a quantidade de linhas desejadas.

```
def gerar(nLins, nCols, min, max):
    from random import randint
    vals = [None] * nLins
    for i in range(nLins):
        vals[i] = [0] * nCols
        for j in range(nCols):
            vals[i][j] = randint(min, max)
    return vals


def mostrar(vals, linMin, linMax, colMin, colMax):
    for i in range(linMin, linMax):
        for j in range(colMin, colMax):
            print(vals[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    print()
    return None




qtd = input().split()
qtdLinhas = int(qtd[0])
qtdColunas = int(qtd[1])
valores = gerar(qtdLinhas, qtdColunas, 10, 99)
mostrar(valores, 0, qtdLinhas, 0, qtdColunas)
```

No caso, gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer a soma de cada linha da matriz e gerar uma nova matriz com as linhas da matriz em ordem crescente da soma de seus valores?

Exemplo:

Quero uma matriz 5 x 6

É gerada a matriz:

```
13 28 45 50 26 10
27 24 22 33 88 11
90 25 85 23 76 55
77 15 31 29 13 14
66 41 50 20 47 11
```

Com ela, é gerada se segunda matriz com as linhas ordenadas conforme a sua soma, na ordem crescente:

```
13 28 45 50 26 10 
77 15 31 29 13 14 
27 24 22 33 88 11 
66 41 50 20 47 11 
90 25 85 23 76 55
```

Visto que suas somas, em ordem crescente dão 172 na primeira linha, 179 na segunda linha, 205 na terceira linha, e assim sucessivamente...

Answer (score 1):

Use o método `sort`.

Você pode passar no parâmetro `key` uma função de callback para gerar o valor que será utilizado para comparar e organizar os itens da matriz. Para esse caso basta usa a função `sum` para somar todos os itens de cada lista. O resultados das somas serão comparados internamente e a matriz será organizada em ordem crescente pelos resultados das somas:

```
valores = [
    [13, 28, 45, 50, 26, 10],
    [27, 24, 22, 33, 88, 11],
    [90, 25, 85, 23, 76, 55],
    [77, 15, 31, 29, 13, 14],
    [66, 41, 50, 20, 47, 11]
]

valores.sort(key=sum)
```

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo? Não consegui aplicar gerando a matriz como mencionei acima e aplicando esse conceito que você passou.

Comment: [Aqui](https://ideone.com/YdwsVQ) tem o código funcionando. Não entendi a dificuldade, visto que você pode usar o código literalmente como está na resposta.